# Can't correctly release PowerManager.WakeLock

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm using `PowerManager.WakeLock` for `Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT` in `Activity`.
It works well but when i'm closing/went to other `Activity` `SensorEventListener` keep turn on/off screen if get sensor changes.

Code sample

```
    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor mLightSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
```

`SensorEventListener` interface method

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] lux = event.values;

    if (lux[0] <= 200) {
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    } else {
        if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

`SensorManager` listener

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mLightSensor);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }

}
```

So how to correctly release and disable `WakeLock`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault is using `SensorEventListener`. Probably it's dublicate `WakeLock.acquire()` and call this every time. The key is to acquire in `onCreate()` and release in `onDestroy()`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```